# Prototype to jQuery conversion - Stuck

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I've been struggling to convert some prototype code I have to jQuery, I've done some looking around google and found a few things but this last segment of code i'm struggling with.

Hopefully someone here could shed some light to what I'm doing wrong....

**This is the prototype code that I'm trying to convert to jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var catCounter = 0;
function addCategory(catId) {
    var cell;
    var row = $('showcategories').insertRow(0);

    if (!catId) {
        catId = $F('category');
    }

    row.id = 'showcategory'+catCounter;

    cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = $('catoption'+catId).text;

    cell = row.insertCell(1);
    cell.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="categories[]" value="'+catId+'">';
    cell.innerHTML += '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeCategory('+catCounter+'); return false;">'
    catCounter++;
}

function removeCategory(catId) {
    $('showcategories').deleteRow($('showcategory'+catId).rowIndex);
}
</script>
```

**Thanks in advance for any help.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure what your question is. What exactly is refusing to work?

Comment: for starters your selectors need either an id symbol (#) or a class symbol (.) in front of them. As it stands they are looking for html dom elements `<showcategories> and <category>` which don't exist

Answer (score 0):

You never need to hide your javascript: `<!--` ... `//-->`

```
function addCategory(catId) {
    var cell;
    var row = $('#showcategories').insertRow(0); //# used to idenitfy IDs

    if (!catId) {
        catId = $('#category'); //same here, just use an ID, not a form element name
    }

    row.id = 'showcategory'+catCounter;

    cell = row.insertCell(0);

    //it's faster to build a string than updating the DOM repeatedly
    var output = = $('#catoption'+catId).text;

    cell = row.insertCell(1);
    output  = '<input type="hidden" name="categories[]" value="'+catId+'">';
    output  += '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeCategory('+catCounter+'); return false;">'
    cell.html(output)
    catCounter++;
}

function removeCategory(catId) {
    $('#showcategories').deleteRow($('#showcategory'+catId).rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Using the `<!--` and `// -->` isn't a bad thing, just probably out of date by today's standards. Also, I believe `$('#category')` needs a `.val()` call (`$F()` is usually a form element value reference).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but still can't get it too work....hmmm I've updated my question above with the rest of the code, hope this helps, thank you everyone so far for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more sleek approach: [jsFiddle code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/bvV4d/1/)

Plugin script file:

```
// Plugin Code (maybe name it jquery-addCategory.js and include it?)
;(function($){

  var catCounter = 0;
  $.fn.extend({
    addCategory: function(catId){
      if (!catId) var catId = $F('category'); // assume $F is a form element value?

      // use return so we can continue chaining
      return this.each(function(){
        var rowId = 'showcategory'+catCounter;

        // I assume catoption[N] is an element with that ID attribute
        // thus my use of '#' prefix for jQuery
        var cell1 = $('<td>').append($('#catoption'+catId).text());
        var cell2 = $('<td>')
          .append($('<input>').attr({
            'type':'hidden',
            'name':'categories[]',
            'value':catId
          })).append($('<input>').attr({
            'type':'button',
            'value':'Remove',
          }).click(function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          }));

        // build the row from the cells above and append it
        var row = $('<tr>').append(cell1).append(cell2);
        $(this).append(row);

        // increase your counter
        catCounter++;
      });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
// the code that goes in your document (#myTable is the table you're attaching the
// the new row on to)
$(function(){
    $('#addRow').click(function(){
        $('#myTable').addCategory($('#category').val());
    });
});
```